# Multiple alternative ProxyJump for ssh profile

Tags: ssh

If there is one end server that can be either connected via proxy server a or proxy server b, but sometimes only one of them is working. Is there a way to specify that the ProxyJump can either be proxy server a or b in `config`? `ProxyCommand` is also fine, **but command line solutions (with arguments or a bash script) is not acceptable.**

```
Host proxya proxyb
    HostName %h.example.com
    User user1

# Proxy servers
Host end-server.example.com
    User user1
    ProxyJump   # Here, how should I configure "either `proxy1` or `proxy2`"?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer relies on a shell script... but executed from within openssh's configuration phase.

### Using `Match`

A [`Match` declaration](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#Match) (which is a superset of a `Host` declaration) allows to apply criteria beyond just hostnames. Among such criteria, there's the `exec` keyword that can run a script to get its return code as true or false result:

> The `exec` keyword executes the specified command under the user's
> shell. If the command returns a zero exit status then the condition is
> considered true. Commands containing whitespace characters must be
> quoted. Arguments to `exec` accept the tokens described in the TOKENS
> section.

It can be used to tell if a proxy is up or not, but can't be used to provide the proxy to use since a boolean kind of result is expected. That means one `Match` entry per possible proxy must be configured. As usual the first matching entry will be used (but see also caveat at the end).

For example place a script within `~/.ssh/bin`:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh/bin
```

For minimal detection at the TCP layer, one can use [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) (`nc` or `nmap` would be other candidates) to check TCP connectivity to provided host and port parameters. It could be made executable to avoid the extra `sh`  in the configuration below.

`~/.ssh/bin/isjumphostavailable.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

MAXDELAY=4
socat /dev/null tcp:"$1":"$2",connect-timeout="$MAXDELAY"
```

Here `socat` won't wait more than 4 seconds and will end immediately if connected (because of `/dev/null`'s EOF). Its return code provides the return code for the script: 0 (=> true) if connection succeeded, not 0 (=> false) otherwise.

To use the script above, the configuration becomes:

```
# Jump hosts' fixed settings
Host proxya proxyb
    Hostname %h.example.com
    User user1

# End server's fixed settings (the factorized part)
Host end-server.example.com
    User user1

# End server's settings with runtime detection (2 lines per distinct proxy)
Match host end-server.example.com exec "sh ~/.ssh/bin/isjumphostavailable.sh proxya.example.com 22"
    ProxyJump proxya

Match host end-server.example.com exec "sh ~/.ssh/bin/isjumphostavailable.sh proxyb.example.com 22"
    ProxyJump proxyb
```

Notes:

- `host` inherits the resolution from previous `Hostname` parameters if any and uses `,` as separator. So `host !proxy*.example.com,*.example.com` could have been used instead to apply to any other end server cases, except the proxies themselves.
- `exec` accepts a single string as parameter: everything must be provided inside double quotes.

Caveat:

- the script will always be evaluated for each matching `exec` entry in the configuration, so even if `proxya` is available and thus used as 1st match, `proxyb` will still be scanned. To avoid this, additional intelligence could be added in the script, for example with an extra file storing state and previous decisions (and that could also be used as cache) to limit the number of times it actually probes. If it's about available routes rather than available servers (eg: did a VPN add some specific route?) then using `ip -json route get ... | jq ...`  in the script could be used without emitting anything. You get the idea.

---

### Using `ProxyCommand`

`ProxyJump` is mostly a wrapper around [`ProxyCommand`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#ProxyCommand). Even `ssh` in verbose mode writes something like:

```
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -v -W '[%h]:%p' proxya
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -v -W '[end-server.example.com]:22' proxya
```

So just use an other wrapper than this one, that will this time pick directly the first available proxy candidate thus overcoming the previous `Match ... exec` caveat. The script will include the list of proxies to try and will use the first found reachable.

`~/.ssh/bin/usefirstavailablejumphost.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

MAXDELAY=4
for p in proxya proxyb; do
    if socat /dev/null tcp:"$p".example.com:22,connect-timeout="$MAXDELAY"; then
        exec ssh -W "[$1]:$2" "$p"
    fi
done
exit 1
```

Note: the pair of `[]` (just copied from `ProxyJump`'s use) is to also allow proper handling of IPv6 addresses with the `-W` parameter.

configuration using this script:

```
# Jump hosts' fixed settings
Host proxya proxyb
    Hostname %h.example.com
    User user1

# End server's settings
Host end-server.example.com
    User user1
    ProxyCommand sh ~/.ssh/bin/usefirstavailablejumphost.sh %h %p
```

Like before, the `Host` line (which doesn't behave exactly as `Match`'s `host`) could also have been written instead as:

```
Host !proxy* *.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks! I specified no shell script as I mainly use VSCode (and also for other servers that do not require a proxy), and sometimes there can be multiple `ProxyJump`s, so using a shell script to establish connection is not suitable in that case, but this is totally fine!

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax for specifying multiple alternative `ProxyJump` servers, but you could do something like this:

```
Host end-server-p1
  Hostname end-server.example.com
  User user1
  ProxyJump proxy1

Host end-server-p2
  Hostname end-server.example.com
  User user1
  ProxyJump proxy2
```

Now you can try `ssh end-server-p1`, and if that doesn't work, you can run `end-server-p2`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is a great solution for a handful end servers, but in my case I have multiple end servers (shared machines with computing resources) so it can generate a long list of machines, but I think in other cases I would use this as this is really elegant!

Comment: If you have a large number of servers, one option would be to generate your ssh configuration from a template (e.g., via Ansible).